# Inserting custom text in JS output

Tags: javascript

I have below line in my js code. i runs from 0 to 2.  I want to put a custom text in place of:  `' + info[i] + '` for each of the i's(over iterations of i). How do I do that?

```
for(var i=0; i < origins.length-1; i++) {
     var results = response.rows[i].elements;
     output += '<tr><td>' + info[i] + '</td><td>' + origins[i] + '</td><td></td><td>' + destinations[i+1] + '</td><td></td><td>' + results[i+1].distance.text + '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Where does the custom text come from? Just put that variable there instead of `info[i]`.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. There are many questions on SO that explain how to center output on the page, just search for them.

Comment: @Barmar I dont have a variable for the custom text. I am new to js. Can you demonstrate  your idea?

Comment: Move your custom text into array variable and use it like `info[i]`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . I want to put a custom text in place of: ' + info[i] + ' for each of the i's(over iterations of i).

Not sure what is "custom text" but assume your custom text should be in an array:

```
var customText = ["Custom text for i=0",
                  "Custom text for i=1",
                  "Custom text for i=2"];

for(var i=0; i < origins.length-1; i++) {
     var results = response.rows[i].elements;
     output += '<tr><td>' + customText[i] + '</td><td>' + //....
}
```

> Also how to align the out-put of the code at the center of my webpage?

This is connected to CSS rather than with JS. Use CSS property `text-align: center` for a `table`, `div` or wharever you want to center.

Answer (score 1):

If the custom text isn't in a variable, just put it directly into the HTML that you're generating:

```
 output += '<tr><td>Custom Text</td><td>' + origins[i] + '</td><td></td><td>' + destinations[i+1] + '</td><td></td><td>' + results[i+1].distance.text + '</td></tr>';
```